# Demand paging terminologies clarification

Tags: memory, memory-management, paging

I have been reading about demand paging and there are a few terminologies I don't understand.

- What is a frame? I read that it is a block of physical memory which    can at least fit in a page ( so a frame can fit one or more pages? ).    But does this physical memory refer to the RAM or the disk storage?.
- Which one of these is true:

  The virtual address space ( which is 4 GiB in 32 bit systems ) is       allocated for one application at a time, so that every application       has 4 GiB virtual address to access to, and each time we switch          application, the OS reconfigures the virtual address space to map to     other other applications. Or the virtual address space is          allocated to several processes? If so, how much virtual memory does      each application get and what happen when it wants more virtual          memory?
- Do we have a page table for each application running, or a common page table for all applications?
- Where does virtual memory fragmentation come from ?

I hope someone can clarify me.

Answer (score 0):

- A frame is a block of physical memory, RAM. I've not heard of frames being larger than pages, I've always understood them synonymous. However, a CPU may allow for frames/pages of different sizes to coexist simultaneously (e.g. *large pages* of 4MB/2MB/1GB size and regular 4KB pages on x86).
- Whether there's a single address space shared by multiple applications or each has its own address space depends on the OS. Windows 3.xx and 9x/Me had a shared address space. Windows NT/2000/XP/etc had individual, per-app address spaces. Not all of the address space is available to an application / applications. A portion is reserved for the OS (kernel, drivers, their data).
- Should be obvious now. One note though... Even with individual address spaces a portion of memory can still be made available in several different address spaces and it may be done by having a common page table in the respective processes. Also, it's very typical for the kernel portion of the address space to be managed by several page tables common to all processes.
- Whether the address space is virtual or not, it can become fragmented. You may want to allocate a contiguous (in terms of the virtual addresses) buffer of, say, 8KB, but you may only have two non-adjacent 4KB regions available.